# How to persist an entity declaring a field with a fixed-size array of a few integers using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections, persistence

I have a class with a field wich references a fixed-size array of integers:

```
class Tracking{
    private int[] tracks;
}
```

What is the best way of mapping the tracks field to a database using JPA (backed by Hibernate)?

The tracks array will contain always 10 elements. I know about @ElementCollection annotation but that implies that I'll end up with two tables (Tracking and Tracking_tracks) and it seems to be unnecessary.

The only approach that comes to mind is to use a String field mapping the 10 numbers into a single String separated by colon. I would make that field persistent (a simple basic @Column) and then in the getters and setters I would perform the parsing into an int[].

Any suggestions? I just want an efficient way of persisting this information. The Tracking objects will be generated permanently, there will be thousands of them and, as the number of integers is always 10, it seems overkilling to persist them into a separate table and perform joins and selects to retrieve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might depend on your persistence provider. but you could try using a special [column definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition%28%29) and let your persistence provider handle the conversion. If this won't work, a lot of persistence provider support custom types. In hibernate they are called [user types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/), open jpa uses [custom field mappings](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.0.1/apache-openjpa-2.0.1/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_mapping_custom_vhandler). Your database may support raw fixed size byte storage.

Comment: Thanks @SpaceTrucker, I was thinking about using Hibernate user types. There are many examples but most of them involve declaring an extra class to map the custom type. Also I don't see where to define the mapper code, most examples only mention an Embeddable type, where the type is mapped to a new class, and it only maps the fields of the embedded class into columns. In this example I want to map the entire int array to a single column. Can you improve your answer providing an example of mapping for the simple entity that I stated in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion made by SpaceTrucker about Hibernate UserType, here is the full code required to provide an Hibernate custom UserType (many thanks to [blog post of Kunaal A Trehan](http://javadata.blogspot.com.ar/2011/07/hibernate-and-user-types.html) for the code in which this class is based on):

```
package org.mypackage;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Type;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;


/**
 * An Hibernate {@link UserType} that allows persisting a list of integers in one single column in the table.
 * Based in code from http://javadata.blogspot.com.ar/2011/07/hibernate-and-user-types.html.
 * 
 * In order to use this as the mapper for a column, use the following in the field of your entity:
 *  @Type(type=IntegerListUserType.NAME)
 *   List<Integer> tracks;
 *  
 * @author dds
 * */
public class IntegerListUserType implements UserType {

    public static final String NAME = "org.mypackage.IntegerListUserType"; //WARNING this must match class name!


    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.VARCHAR };
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return List.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        if (x != null)
            return x.hashCode();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
            SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        List<Integer> list = null;
        String nameVal = rs.getString(names[0]);
        if (nameVal != null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(nameVal, ",");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                String number = (String) tokenizer.nextElement();
                list.add(Integer.valueOf(number));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
            SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            st.setString(index, serialize((List<Integer>) value));
        }
    }

    private String serialize(List<Integer> list) {
        StringBuilder strbul = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            strbul.append(iter.next());
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                strbul.append(",");
            }
        }
        return strbul.toString();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        else {
            List<Integer> newObj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            List<Integer> existObj = (List<Integer>) value;
            newObj.addAll(existObj);
            return newObj;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        Object deepCopy = deepCopy(value);
        if (!(deepCopy instanceof Serializable))
            return (Serializable) deepCopy;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException {
        return deepCopy(original);
    }

}
```

Note that I'm converting String to List < Integer >  instead of int[] just for simplicity.